# Regular Expression - Two Numbers Between Slash

Tags: regex, python-re

I'd like to capture the regular expression of two numbers between a slash within a string (basically a date: dd/mm). I have this so far:

```
\d{2}\/\d{2}
```

This seems to capture most of what I want, however it also captures

```
2002/06
```

Which has four numbers on the left hand side. I only want it to match if it has two numbers either side of the slash. How do I do this?

Comment: Specify the start of the line using `^`, use a positive lookbehind to check for whitespace before the numbers, or use a negative lookbehind to make sure the match does not have any numbers directly before it.

Answer (score 0):

Add word boundaries around it.

```
\b\d{2}\/\d{2}\b
```